# Why isn't font rendered in HTML when surronded by &quot;

Tags: c#, html, html-entities, html-encode

I have some HTML stored in a database and I am generating an static HTML file out of it. However when i open the file in the browser, the font doesn't render as I expect it.

I have tracked down the problem and I see it is because of `& quot;`

```
<p><span style="font-family: &quot;Roboto Regular&quot;;">Some text</span></p>
```

Now if I replace the `& quot;` with `double quotes`, it works fine.

This is also generated through C#. What is the best approach to fix this?
Should I just use `Replace function` to convert them to quotes or is there a library that I can use to do it more efficiently? or is it even simpler to fix.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` (and `Encode`) to handle this sort of thing.

However you should be asking yourself why your font string includes HTML encoded characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. The reason is that it is coming from SummerNote editor, encoded like that. Your solution seems to partially work. Now I am seeing `&nbsp` are getting converted to `Â`  character. Any ideas why?

Comment: That's odd. `Â` should be encoded as `&Acirc;` for a capital a, with a circumflex accent. `&nbsp;` is a space.

Comment: So the HTML has the `&nbsp;` and I was expecting to see space instead of it but it is showing as `Â`.

Comment: I created a simple test project that just did `var result = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("foo&nbsp;bar");` and it decoded it correctly. I think there must be something else going on. I suggest you ask another question with a short example (ideally one line) of the code that goes wrong so we can reproduce it and trace the problem.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is spewed out as is and not parsed until it reaches the browser. This is a security measure to ensure that no malicious code can be run in the browser. I will recommend you use the Replace function you suggest. If you want to take security to the next level, I will suggest you encode the opening and closing braces of HTML tags and including that inside your Replace method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I believe Robin's solution has potential to fix it by doing the decode.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain why...

```
<p><span style="font-family: &quot;Roboto Regular&quot;;">Some text</span></p>
```

Since you said c#, your code clearly shows that HtmlDecode doesn't decode quotes for font-family. This is caused by copy-paste html to database while using HtmlEncode as below.

```
HtmlEncode("<p><span style="font-family: "Roboto Regular";">Some text</span></p>");
```

As you notice above usage of quote in another quote is illegal in html unless it is escaped. That is why HtmlDecode thinks this is escaped quote and leaves it as it is.

SOLUTION: You can replace the font-family quotes with single quote before HtmlEncode but this would create SQL issue to address which is replacing single quote with double single quotes. Off course you need to reverse it after HtmlDecode. HtmlEncoding again or replacing with double quotes would not fix the issue since you are creating another illegal quotes in quotes. That is why you need to simply replace [&quote;] with single quote ['] and you can do this in frontend.

```
("<p><span style="font-family: &quot;Roboto Regular&quot;;">Some text</span></p>").replace("&quot;", "'");
```